# How to create an Sql table from SELECT with a multiple row DISTINCT constraint?

Tags: postgresql, select, prepared-statement

I want to create a table from a SELECT statement based on a multiple row DISTINCT, but PostgreSQL does not allow me to do it.

I need to create a table where the elements were previously selected from another table and they are all unique.

Here's my try:

```
CREATE TABLE new_name AS (

   SELECT DISTINCT(table.field1, table.field2), table.field1, table.field2, 
   FROM ...
   WHERE ...

);
```

If I run this statement, PostgreSQL says:

> ERROR: column "row" has pseudo-type record

How could I solve this problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`distinct` is ***NOT*** a function. It always operates on **all** columns of the result.

The difference between `select distinct (foo), bar` and `select distinct foo, bar` is the same as the difference between `select (foo), bar` and `select foo, bar`. The parenthesis is just "noise".

When you write `select (foo,bar)` you are actually creating an anonymous record type in Postgres which results in a single column that has two attributes - which is not what you actually want.

---

As you are using Postgres, you can use the (proprietary) operator [`DISTINCT ON`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT) which - in contrast to the standard `DISTINCT` - *does* operate on a sub-set of the columns.

You **have** to specify an ORDER BY in that case to define which of the rows to take if there is more than one with the same combination of `(field1, field2)`.

```
CREATE TABLE new_name 
AS 
SELECT DISTINCT ON (table.field1, table.field2), 
       table.field1, 
       table.field2, 
       .....
FROM ...
WHERE ...
ORDER BY ..
```

If you want to stick to ANSI SQL you will need a window function for this:

```
create table new_name
as
select column1, column2, column3, column4, column5, column6
from (
   select column1, column2, column3, column4, column5, column6, 
          row_number() over (partition by column1, column2 order by ...) as rn 
   from the_table
   where ...
) t
where rn = 1;
```

For a large table, `DISTINCT ON` is probably faster than the solution with the window function.

Comment: It worked, thanks! I did not need the IN ORDER clause.

Comment: @DavideChicco.it You should use an `ORDER BY` if you want consistent results. From the manual: "*Note that the "first row" of each set is unpredictable unless ORDER BY is used*": http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT

Comment: But I'm not interested in the order, later I'll do just a COUNT(*)... should I use the ORDER BY clause anyway?

Comment: The `order by` is necessary to get a consistent result if you run this more than once. See this example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/df4ef/4 if you don't care about which values are in the non-distinct columns, then you can leave out the `order by`